# Show $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} r_{k}\chi _{A_{k}} = f$

Tags: measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, measurable-functions

My Attemp:
Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ a measurable space and $:X→[0,\infty]$ measurable and , $(r_{n})_{n \in {\mathbb{N}}}$ is a sequence  $(0,\infty)$  such that $r_{n} \to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r_{n}= \infty$ , where
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        A_1:=\{x\in X: r_1 \leq f(x) \} \hspace{3ex} & \text{and}  \hspace{3ex} g_1
        :=r_1 \chi_{A_1}\\
       & \vdots \\
       A_k:=\{x\in X : g_{k-1}(x) + r_k \leq f(x) \} \hspace{3ex} & \text{and}  \hspace{3ex} g_k:=g_{k-1} + r_k \chi_{A_k}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
I did a proof that:$\{A_k\}_{k\in { \mathbb{N}}}\in \mathcal{M}$ and i proved until moment that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} r_{k}\chi _{A_{k}}(x) \leq f(x)$  like that:
(Just i considered the case where  $x\in A_k$ only for finites $k$ and i dont care the case where $x\in A_k$ for all $k$). Because all element of the sequence $B_n=\sum_{k}^{n}{r_k \chi_{A_{k}}}\in \overline {\mathbb{R}}$ (real number extend)  satisfy that $B_n(x)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in X$ then $\lim\sup B_n(x)\leq f(x)$
. I need to show the other inequality for show the equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick some $x$. Let $I= \{ k | x \in A_k \}$.
 Note that we always have $\sigma = \sum_{k \in I} r_k \le f(x)$.

If $f(x) = \infty$ then $x \in A_k $ for all $k$ and hence
$g_n(x) =r_1+\cdots + r_n$ for all $k$. Hence $\lim_n g_n(x) = \infty$.

Otherwise $f(x) < \infty$. Suppose $\sigma < f(x)$. Let $n$ be the first $n \notin I$ such that $\sigma+r_n \le f(x)$, however, this implies that
$x \in A_n$ and so $n \in I$ which is a contradiction. Hence
$\sigma = f(x)$.

Comment: Excusme cooper.hat, when you suppose that $∉$,this imply $x\notin A_n$ then $+_n >()$ so dont exist one $n$ such that satisfy the assumption, can you help me please?.

Comment: There is no contradiction if $\sigma+r_n > f(x)$, in general there will be an infinite number of indices such that this is true.

Comment: in one moment i want to put one idea , can you read please, im not sure about, thank you cooper.hat im confuse, please wait, im writing my idea for the last part

Comment: Let $g_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} r_{k}\chi _{A_{k}}(x) \leq f(x)$ (it was prove in the first part of my attempt) and  $ I= \{ k | x \in A_k \}$. Suppose that $n$ is the first integer such that $n\notin I$ then $x\notin A_n$ hence $g_{n-1}(x) + r_n > f(x)$ but $g_n(x)<f(x)$ then if add $r_n$ in the inequality $f(x)<g_n(x)+r_n< f(x)+r_n$  because $g_{n-1}(x)+r_n=g_n(x)+r_n$ so when i will take limit when $n\to\infty$ and use $r_n\to 0$ then $f(x)=\lim g_n(x)$. Can you help me please, if i take mistake in some place i will apreciate your help cooper.hat (i use your help in this part)

Comment: Yes, that is a nice way to prove it. There must be an infinite number of $n$ **not** in $I$ and $r_n \to 0$. That will work too. Basically the squeeze theorem to show $g_n(x) \to f(x)$.

Comment: (Was that what you were asking?)

Comment: i just have reputation 13, but i will like to chat with you, im agree with your answer, is will prove that $g_n(x)\to f(x)$ thank you so much cooper.hat

Comment: I can chat for 5 mins, but don't know how to initiate?

Comment: my reputation is very slow so i can to chat, thank you cooper.hat

Comment: I created a chat room called copper.hat. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107011/copper-hat

Comment: I only have a few minutes, I will need to finish at 1700 PST.

Comment: i don know too how to chat, but thank you so much, you really help me

Comment: look that appear in my chat You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the

Comment: Click on the link in my last comment. Oh, can you not do that?

Comment: sorry, i cant other day we will chat, thank you

Comment: Ok. If you have specific questions you can send me an email. My address is in my bio.

Comment: thank you so much..cooper.hat